# how to traverse a tree and create a path of the traversed path by matching some values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a tree which a multiple child nodes in it.

I need to traverse the tree and based on that I need to make a string path export.

For example my object is,

```
Public myObject()
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
public int ID { get; set; }
Public int ProductId {get; set;}    
}
```

for the above object I have a Tree like `<TreeNode<myObject>>`

so the above Tree will have many child and parent nodes.
I also have List of myobject `<List>myObject` (may be some 5 items)
in which I need to check whether the list of 5 items Id is matching with any parent or Child of the tree. If it is matching then i need to construct a path like below.

for example if the Tree is matching like 4 th child Parent Node 1 > Child1 > in which another Child2 is matching the Id then I need to take abbreviation from top to bottom and construct a path.

How to achieve this, I tried to do through for each items in the list and traversing through the tree but I am not able to proceed.

My Ultimate Target will be like below

```
<TreeNode<myObject>>treelist

foreach(var obj in myObject) // myobject is list of object
{
//Find the node where this obj is available in the treelist
//may be obj.Id ==treelist>>child>>node>>Child.Id
//Then obj.Abbreviation =treelist.child.Abbreviation/node.abbreviation/child.abbreviation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you pseudo-code, you can implement real code

```cs
void traversetree(mytreeNode, dictionary<int, list<myObject>> matches)
{
    foreach(node in mytreeNode)
    {
        if (!matches.ContainsKey(node.myObject.id) // assuming you know how to get the object from the node
            matches.Add(node.myObject.id, new List<node.myObject>() { node.myObject });
        else
        {
            if (matches[mytreeNode.myObject.id][0].Something == node.myObject.Something)
                matches[node.myObject.id].Add(node.myObject);
        }  
        traversetree(node, matches);
    }
}
```

That will get you flattened nodes with matching data. Now just build you "Path"

```cs
foreach(kvp in matches)
    Console.WriteLine("ID:" + kvp.Key + string.Join("\\", kvp.Value));
```

Let me know if I missed anything..

Comment: Can you please explain me that how this will work as traversing?

Comment: for better understanding I have modified my code please check it.

Comment: @Samaritan_Learner My method works on the recursive iteration of the tree. Now, few things I did not figure out from your question. For example, "tree" is broad term. I can create a class, like a composite pattern, which is naturally a tree. You have not provided types of your tree nodes. Is `TreeNode` a `winforms.treenode`? Or a a type you building? etc. Where tree node holds your object, in which property? I am also not clear on principals of matching the id or other field. My method traverses the tree and build flat list of related nodes (related the way I understood it).

Comment: @Samaritan_Learner Once you have a flat list, you just combine your related nodes. A graph for this problem would be helpful

Comment: I got the issue now, Thanks for the answer. What I have done is that in DB itself I have the parent child mapping so created a function to generate the string for all the items so that regardless of tree it will have it is own full path everywhere

Comment: Marking it as answer because it satisfies the original question. so it would be helpful to someone else as well.

Comment: Thanks. Glad you've sorted this out